# Install and enable APC for php 5.4.3 on wampserver 2.2 on windows 7x64

Tags: php

I am trying to install PHP accelerator like apc for a symfony project .
The problem is that the apc is not appearing in localhost/?phpinfo=1, however it does appear on wamp>php>extensions menu tray with options php_apc enabled.And also when i try localhost/test.symfony.com/web/config.php , it seems that symfony project does not detects the apc.

I have trying to resolve this problem for the past 3 days  :( .

Here are my steps that i have made to install and enable apc.dll

1.In the folder of the extensions i have placed the apc.dll 
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext

I have downloaded the apc.dll from http://dev.freshsite.pl/php-accelerators/apc.html for the version APC 3.1.9 for PHP 5.4 vc9 (Win7/2008) as per my configuration

2.I have set up the extension for the dll in php.ini as below in Dynamic Extensions 
extension=php_apc.dll

and in the  Module Settings section i have placed the following:-

[APC]

apc.enabled = 1

apc.shm_segments = 1

apc.shm_size = 128M

apc.max_file_size = 10M

apc.stat = 1

3.Restart wampserver

MY php info:

Compiler    -MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)

Architecture    -x64

Thread Safety   -enabled

apache version  -2.4.2

php version     -5.4.3

OS           -window 7

Thanks you for kind reply :)

Comment: Unless you are pretty sure what are you doing, you should not pick x64 architecture for web server.   So, pick x86, select your apc dll version (apc_3113_beta_php54_vc9_win7-2008.dll for example) and edit the correct php.ini file C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini (exists two php.ini, you can check the correct direction in the phpinfo).